# Python module for log file parsing

Tags: python-2.7

---

Is there a module in python that can be used to parse log files, i.e print the line in the log file that contains the word the user enters for parsing. Ex. if user enter Mar 18 2014, the script must display the line in the log file containing Mar 18 2014.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not open the file and search manually? Its only a couple lines of code

Comment: Is does it have to be with python? It cant be done is shell much shorter. In python: for line in open("file"): if "search_string" in line: print line

Comment: Forgot to mention that in shell/bash you can do: $ grep -i "pattern" file.name

Comment: @user3563243 How did you implement it? Python or grep? Also up vote :-)

Comment: used grep, @Simply_Me !